# add values with same name in a list of tuple in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples like this

```
[(300.0, 'g', 'peanuts'),
 (0.5, 'tsp', 'salt'),
 (2.0, 'tsp', 'oil'),
 (300.0, 'g', 'peanuts'),
 (1.0, 'tsp', 'salt'),
 (3.0, 'tsp', 'oil')]
```

I want to add up the quantity if they have the same name

```
[(600.0, 'g', 'peanuts'),
 (1.5, 'tsp', 'salt'),
 (5.0, 'tsp', 'oil')]
```

I try to take items from list by using for...in loop but have no clues for further steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict` to keep track of the totals for each name.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
l = [(300.0, 'g', 'peanuts'), (0.5, 'tsp', 'salt'), (2.0, 'tsp', 'oil'), (1.0, 'cup', 'mung'), (0.5, 'tsp', 'salt'), (0.75, 'tsp', 'pink'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'garlic'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'onion'), (0.125, 'tsp', 'pepper'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'turmeric'), (1.0, 'tsp', 'oil'), (1.0, 'cup', 'soy')]
d = defaultdict(int)
for v, *k in l: 
    d[tuple(k)] += v
res = [(v, *k) for k, v in d.items()]
print(res)
```

Comment: I am not allowed to import anything for this assignment. Is there any way to solve it by only using loops and if stateemnt?

Comment: @JiayiMeng Yes, you can use a normal dict: `d = {}` and `for v, *k in l: d[tuple(k)] = d.get(tuple(k), 0) + v`

Answer (score 0):

You want to "extract **one object**" to summarize a **list of objects**.

That is what the "[reduce](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/)" function is for:

```
from functools import reduce

my_tuples = [(300.0, 'g', 'peanuts'), (0.5, 'tsp', 'salt'), (2.0, 'tsp', 'oil'), (1.0, 'cup', 'mung'), (0.5, 'tsp', 'salt'), (0.75, 'tsp', 'pink'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'garlic'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'onion'), (0.125, 'tsp', 'pepper'), (0.25, 'tsp', 'turmeric'), (1.0, 'tsp', 'oil'), (1.0, 'cup', 'soy')]

def sum_stuff(current_sum_dict, peanut_tuple):
    if peanut_tuple[2] in current_sum_dict.keys():
        current_sum_dict[peanut_tuple[2]] += peanut_tuple[0]
    else:
        current_sum_dict[peanut_tuple[2]] = peanut_tuple[0]
    return current_sum_dict


print(reduce(sum_stuff, my_tuples, {}))
```

reduces takes two arguments (plus an optional initializer).

The second argument is your list in that code sample I called it `my_tuples`.

The first one is a "function" that takes two arguments:

- the current "reduced value" (at the begining it is either the first element of the list or your initializer if you specified one)
- the current item of the list

`reduce` function loops on your whole list and updates the "reduced" value at every iteration.

reduce is part of the official and native `functools` package you don't need to install any extra package to use it.

Very often you see people using a lambda expression instead of defining an actual function especially if the function is very short:

In this example I use a lambda expression to count the 'peanuts'

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[0] if b[2] == 'peanuts' else a, my_tuples, 0)
```